# API fetch is failing using axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to fetch data from API by using axois get and it requires key and token for authentication.I am using axios interceptors for authentication but I am unable to fetch API. Here is the code I have tried so far.Where is the problem in code?I am unable to figure out.When I replace URL with some other URL it successfully fetches data but when I put back this URL it does not fetch data.
Response Should be this : https://app.arrivy.com/api/tasks/5078426505969664/forms

edited:
Here is console log resposes:
[image]

Here is network tab response:

[image]

```
import React , {useState , useCallback} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const accessToken = 'qxCMYME6XKuQrGkbqNbH8Q';
const accessKey='3809a96d-4211';
const apiURL= 'https://app.arrivy.com/api';





axios.interceptors.request.use(

config => {

    config.headers.authorization = `Bearer $ {accessToken},{accessKey} `;
    return config;

} ,
error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});


function Fetch (){


const [taskID , setTaskId] = useState(0);

const fetchData = useCallback( async () => {

    console.log(taskID);
    try {

       const result = await axios.get(`${apiURL}/tasks/${taskID}/forms`)
       console.log('fetch successfully');
       console.log(result.data);


    }

    catch (err){

        console.log('error');

    }

});

const handleSubmit=(evt)=>{

    evt.preventDefault();

    alert (`id: ${taskID}`)


}

return(

    <div>
        <div>
            <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>

            <label>
               TASK ID:
               <input type="text"
                value={taskID}
                placeholder="Input task ID here"
                onChange={e=>setTaskId(e.target.value)}
                required
               />

            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

            <button onClick={fetchData}>GET FORMS</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
);}

export default Fetch;
```

Comment: Are you trying to submit your form or call `fetchData` when the button is clicked, because both appear to be happening?

Comment: @DrewReese submit button is to submit taskID and GET FORM button is to fetch data via API.

Comment: What's the error you're facing?

Comment: @xehpuk it always shows error in console (see catch block in fetchdata function). instead of showing data which is in JSON format

Comment: Default `type` for `button` elements is `type="submit"`, so.... do the math on what happens. As xehpuk asks, is there any error message? What is the failure? Please provide more context and evidence of debugging, i.e. the response you are receiving in the network tab of your browser's dev tools. Your "expected response" requires the token, so we just see unauthorized - "Wrong Credentials".

Comment: @DrewReese see the question I have edited it.

Comment: Can see what the xhr error is? Looking at your code this line might the issue `Bearer $ {accessToken},{accessKey} `. this template literal is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use global axios tokens like this:

```
import React , {useState , useCallback} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const accessToken = 'qxCMYME6XKuQrGkbqNbH8Q';
const apiURL= 'https://app.arrivy.com/api';

axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = 'UR9SZbYX8rskOeDzFQlACi';
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Key'] = '745991d9-8064';
```

This key and token then can be used in every API call.